# Python subprocess call for apache jena fuseki server

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to start jena fuseki server in python .For this i initially tried with python **os.system()** .For which it is working

```
os.system("./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds")
```

I need this with **subprocess.Popen()**

```
subprocess.Popen(['./fuseki-server', '--update', '--mem','/ds'])
```

But the command is not executing with this. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried it without `'./'`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using subprocess.call() to the full path.

```
path = '/full/path/to/fuseki-server --update --mem /ds'
args = path.split()

subprocess.call(args)
```

Not totally sure this will work, but hope it helps.